# setting a captive portal using freeradius + mysql + apache

Tags: mysql, apache, portal, freeradius

can someone try to tell me the difficulty level of this kind of wifi captive portal setup.

im knowledgeable in networking, not much in php/mysql but enough skills to setup my own webserver. and a 4/10 knowledge in radius.

here's the scenario

1) a user will be directed in a captive portal page upon connecting in `guest_ssid`

2) a registration page will appear and the user will input a couple of fields (e.g email, name, etc.).

3) after submitting it will allow access to the network (valid only for 3hours with 512Kb bandwidth)

i understand that i needed the ff:

- radius for (accounting and bandwidth limitting)
- apache for webserver
- mysql for user storage
- pfsense for the redirection to the portal / wall garden

1) and so, i followed a guide in which i managed to install freeradius with mysql and apache.
i have a table called `radius` with these tables

Tables in radius

- radacct
- radcheck
- radgroupcheck
- radgroupreply
- radpostauth
- radreply
- radusergroup

as i understand in the document, i should place my accounts inside `radcheck` table.

```
+----+----------+----------------+----+-------+
| id | username |   attribute    | op | value |
+----+----------+----------------+----+-------+
| 1  | john     | Cleartext-Pass | := | 12345 |
+----+----------+----------------+----+-------+
```

2) then inside my /var/www/html are `login.php` `login_success.php` `check_login.php`

Check_login.php

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="radius"; // Database name
$tbl_name="radcheck"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$Cleartext-Pass")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

*!! all php codes here are working using my other database; which consisted only a table and user and password fields !!*

i guess my question is, how do i make my php login work on a freeradius that is using mysql as a user storage? - not even sure if i placed the syntax/values correctly in my php

and how do i implement session limit (3hours) and bandwidth limiting in freeradius?

Comment: For the delay/bandwidth you should loot at freeradius accounting (radacct.acctsessiontime/radacct.acctstopdelay for delay, and radacct.acctinputoctets/radacct.acctoutputoctets for bandwidth). I have no experience in that, but maybe it will help.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this as I am trying to do almost the exact same thing?

Comment: Did any of you guys solve this? @James I need the guide too